# capturing keyboard interrupts during while executing Python scripts

Tags: python, bash, keyboard-events

I am executing a bash script in Python using the tempfile and subprocess like so:

```
 with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as scriptfile:
                scriptfile.write(teststr)
                scriptfile.flush()
                subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', scriptfile.name])
```

Here, teststr has the entire bash script within it.
My question is, once it starts to execute, it doesn't capture keyboard interrupts like `Ctrl+c` and `ctrl+z`.

Is there anyway to interrupt the execution of the script once  it has begun?

Comment: Show us your bash script.  It probably traps `SIGINT`...

Comment: Can't reproduce. Even if child process executes `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)` and enters infinite loop, signal is successfully delivered to Python parent (as it should be: entire process group is affected) where it raises an appropriate exception.
EDIT: Oh, never mind: the child keeps running and *that* is the problem, probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the problem is that Python parent process receives `SIGINT` from `Ctrl+C` and quits with unhandled exception, but the child ignores signal and keeps running. That is the only scenario I was able to reproduce. Actual problem may differ. Catching exception and killing subprocess explicitly with `SIGKILL` may work.

Instead of `subprocess.call`:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', scriptfile.name])
try:
    proc.wait()
except:
    proc.kill()
    raise
```

Comment: Never use naked excepts: if you don't know what you're catching, then you don't know how to handle it. `except KeyboardInterrupt` is what you want here. And SIGKILL is a last resort, not a first one; SIGTERM is what you send when you want to give an arbirtrary process a chance at orderly clean-up.